# How do I know if a tcp connection is finished in java?

Tags: java, tcp

How do I know if a TCP connection is terminated? I have an `AsynchronousSocketChannel` and after I open it, every time I call `isOpen()` afterwards the result is `true`.

I am accepting the TCP connection from a web browser.

Comment: TCP sockets remain open until they are closed(i.e you have done what you need to and want to quit the connection).

Comment: I don't respond to the TCP connection I just forward it to another server(like a proxy) and I need to know the state of web browser and remote server tcp and if they exchanged the {FIN,FINACK,ACK} messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TCP connection is up until you get an IOException writing to it or an EOS reading from it. The APIs like isOpen() don't tell you about the connection state, they tell you about the Socket or Channel state, i.e. what you have done to it yourself.